# Логика htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

мне нужна ссылка вида

```
site.com/events
```

но получается, только так

```
site.com/Events
```

с кодом .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^Events(.*)$ /events.php?$1 ,
```

если же сделать код так

```
RewriteRule ^events(.*)$ /events.php?$1
```

выводится ошибка 500

можно конечно написать

```
RewriteRule ^events/(.*)$ /events.php?$1
```

(слэш в конце events)

но мне нужно именно без слеша.

Кто знает в чем дело и как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что после подстановки .htaccess идет на новый круг совпадений, в результате events.php подпадает под events(.*) Даже если подставить флаг [L].
У вас все решается довольно просто:

```
^events(.*)$ -> ^events([^\.].*)$
```

Плюс добавить редирект с events на events.php

```
^events$ /events.php
```

Можно сделать и за одну регулярку, но это будет очень некрасиво

Comment: ой. а можно полную строчку, а то не много не понял

Comment: адрес имеет вид site.ru/events/ , а нужно site.ru/events

Comment: Правило

    RewriteRule ^events$ /events.php

должно как раз-таки пересылать с site/events на site/events.php